# Secure login with additional context information passed through (which also needs to be secure)

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, man-in-the-middle

My web application will be launched through existing thick client applications. When launched, an HTTP POST request will be generated including information like the userID and additional context information (basically stuff like the target user's name, birthday, etc.).

My plan for authentication is for there to be a look-up table in the database. If the username is already there, automatically login the user, but if there is no entry in the database, redirect the user to an initial login page which will be used to create that database entry.

My question is how to secure this against MITM and other security holes. How can the request generated through the thick client be on an SSL connection? Doesn't an SSL connection have to be authenticated with the username (and password) first? And if so, will the additional context information be publicly exposed until the user is logged in?

Sorry if this is a basic security 101 question. References on where to read up on security basics would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, SSL does not require any username or password to work.  SSL only encrypts the data between the client and the server.  You could serve an entirely anonymously accessed site via SSL.  Most of the time, people equate SSL and logins because you want to encrypt your login credentials and any of the information accessed using those credentials.

If you want to use your method, simply post the User ID and other information to your SSL site.  The post and any response will be encrypted.  If using a web page, it would look something like this.

```
<form method="POST" action="https://mysite.com/login">
```

Generating from an application, just use the https:// when creating your URL to post to.

Regarding any other security concerns, we do not have enough information to speak about the overall security of your planned deployment, but the above should take care of your initial questions about SSL and encryption.